# Customize quick action dialog for android

Tags: android, android-activity, customization, quickaction

I'm developing an application in which I have to show quick action dialog on click of a button. Here is an example how I want it to implement.

[image: What I want to implement.]

Till now I could not figure out how to make a custom quick action dialog. But I have tried using an activity and some what I'm near what I have to achieve. Here is what I have done till now.

On click of the button I'm passing intent to the activity:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.points) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on points",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PointsActionMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

And I have used `styles.xml` to make the activity transparent.

Styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Implementing these things I have got this UI on my screen. 
[image: Reached till here]

Now, I have two questions:

1. I have used activity and designed a layout to work for my needs. Is
   there any easy way to implement this using quick action dialog. I
   have gone through 2-3 examples for that, but I was unable to
   customize it according to my need.
2. As far as I have implemented using an activity, it is showing in the center of the screen, can I change the default place of the
   activity to right corner as shown in the picture.

Either of the answer can help me.

Any kind of help will be appreciated for this.

Comment: Have you tried `android:gravity` for number problem #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. Here it is now what it looks like.

[image: What I found]

Integrated the following code for setting it's position.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = this.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = 80; // x position
    wmlp.y = 60; // y position
```

Comment: Have you tested it on other screen sizes and densities? Unless you only want it to run on a single device, this might introduce you headaches later on.

Comment: @Anupam I also have develop similar kind of popup dialog. Can you share your code of popup window ?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider what happens on different devices and screen sizes.
Consider scaling the pixels to dp with this:

```
int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

**EDIT:**

```
wmlp.x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
wmlp.y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Where should I implement this?

Comment: I edited my response. - That function converts whatever "pixel" value you provide into the appropriate "dp" value.